# horizontal image gallery - white-space: nowrap messing up max-height: 100% on Firefox for Android

Tags: android, html, css, firefox, image-gallery

I like to build horizontally laid out, vertically-fitted image galleries like this:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
   <body style="height: 100%">
      <div class="someContainer" style="height: 100%">
         <div class="galleryContaineer" style="height: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
            <img width="1000" height="2000" style="max-height: 90%; width: auto; height: auto" />
            ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This seemed to be fairly well supported... Well, until i tried it on Firefox for Android (31.0 on 4.4.4). Which probably no one uses.

Apparently the `nowrap` causes Firefox to compute the body's height way to big, which kills the vertical-fitting. Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5a6V/7/ which you might have to open unwrapped http://fiddle.jshell.net/W5a6V/7/show/ (if this link ends up dead, just inspect the proper fiddle and open the result iframe's `src` in a new tab) because the iframe somehow fixes this mess.

Sorry @jsfiddle for a whole bunch of binary :) — alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours I resorted to a technique which I gave up for the less CSS-heave approach shown above.
You have to force Firefox to limit the body's height to the actual viewport's height, which can be done with media queries, like this:

```
@media screen and (min-device-height:   0px) { body { max-height:   0px; } }
@media screen and (min-device-height: 100px) { body { max-height: 100px; } }
@media screen and (min-device-height: 200px) { body { max-height: 200px; } }
```

And so on. I guess there is a cool name for this. It's pretty robust and helped me in circumstances where the `img`s had to be individually wrapped in some kind of container, too, think captions.

If one of your containers is positioned absolutely, you might have to apply the max-height to it, instead of the body.

While I fixed this - see answer below - other ideas are highly appreciated.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5a6V/9/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/W5a6V/9/show/ respectively.

---

Update: Forgot to check back in Webkitland... where it does break the original layout. Gotta target Firefox by adding `and (-moz-touch-enabled: 1)` to the media query. Yuck!

Comment: Just ran into a similiar issue and googled my own question, but unfortunately unhelpful answer... in this case, i added `maximum-scale=1` to the `<meta name="viewport" />`'s `content`, because otherwise firefox would assume that the (horizontally very wide) page has to fit into the (portrait) viewport at a very low automatic minimum scale, resulting in a vertically very tall virtual viewport/page. the virtual viewport has the same aspect ratio as the device - if you position something at `top: 50%` it ends up very far away...